# How to avoid char[] garbage in Java?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

My application constructs **very long strings** (each of about 30000 characters). Due to this, I am running out of memory, as well as I see that there is lot of garbage collection of `char[]` objects. This is because I am using the Stringbuilder, which possibly uses `char[]` internally.

Also, a major part of this huge string is fixed (say 29800 characters). So, what varies is only the remaining part. If I create a static String and then concatenate them, I still end up with the same GC results, since '+' gets compiled as `StringBuilder` internally.

Is there an efficient way to construct long strings in Java, without GCing?

**EDIT:**

Some sample (pseudo) code snippet:

```
private static String getString() {

    StringBuilder sb = getStringBufferFromPool();
    sb.append(<variable_part>);
    sb.append(<constant_part>);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a larger heap size?

Comment: How about showing some relevant code. 30k chars is 60kbytes, and you can create quite a lot of those Strings too before memory becomes a real issue. Short lived objects are GC'd efficiently, so String concatenation isn't that bad unless you're doing it in a tight loop.

Comment: 30k char is not much, but you can always write to a file instead ( using less memory by writing to a file as you go along)

Comment: @McN: Yes, I have set a heap size of 8 GB. I have profiled my code with Jprofiler too, and it shows the char[] objects growing very fast during the time when the long strings are created.

Comment: @Kayaman: There are 20000 such Strings and possibly other operations (like concatenation) happening on them, which is creating problems.

Comment: As soon as I reduce the size of the strings, it does not GC much!

Comment: You should create a specialized data-structure to represent the strings, and avoid to replicate the constant part of 29800 chars in every instance.

Comment: @bpositive 20k*60KB is still not a lot. It's very unclear if you have an actual problem, or if you just don't like that the GC is doing his job. If only you were to show your code.

Comment: @Kayaman: GC is undesirable in my application since it runs in realtime and I can't point you to the exact code due to proprietary issues. I have added some pseudo code in the question now.

Comment: @bpositive Unfortunately the pseudocode doesn't help much. Based on what you can tell me, I have very few suggestions. One recourse might be to spend some time tuning the GC to see if you can get the performance to an acceptable level.